# Correct typings for React Typescript Button props with named function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In Tab.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  title: string;
  index: number;
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
}

const Tab: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, onClick, index }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        {title}
      </button>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Tab;
```

Trying to use it with a named function

```
const changeTab = (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  console.log(e);
};

return <Tab onClick={changeTab}></Tab>
```

I have tried all different combinations of the types and can not get it to work currently receiving following error:

```
'{ onClick: (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': title, index, active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining because you stated that props would include two other items (`title` and `index`), but they aren't present.

You either need to make them optional:

```js
interface Props {
  title?: string;
  index?: number;
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
}
```

Or add the properties:

```js
return <Tab onClick={changeTab} title={''} index={0}></Tab>
```

Comment: Thanks you are right. New to type script and the errors are sometimes a little tricky to understand what it is complaining about!